# "Overload" subscript-assignment operation in c++ 14

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

### Issue:

I need to construct an array that stores one type of data but appears as another type for memory saving. Only the subscript operator (`[]`) is required.

Say, I have an array `arr` that appears as fp32 but stores int8 internally:
When reading a value from arr by `arr[i]`, overloading the subscript operator that returns by value just works. However when assigning a value with syntax like `arr[i]=somevalue`, as I cannot cast `int8_t` to `float32_t` with reference, I cannot modify the inside value.

### What I tried:

Defining a separate method `set(unsigned int index, float32_t value)` would be a simple solution, but it will require modifying all other code interacting with the array, thus not favored.

I considered using a template datatype for internal storing, and overloading its operator=. However, in this case the returned type of the [] operator cannot be determined and I cannot proceed further.

### Code

```
// dummy cast functions
int8_t complex_downcast(double x) { 
    return x;
}
double complex_upcast(int8_t x) {
    return x;
}

// current structure
template <typename T, unsigned int N> struct buffer {
    int8_t v[N];

    T get(int i) const {
        return complex_upcast(v[i]);
    }

    T operator[](int i) const {
        return get(i);
    }

    void set(int i, T v) {
        this->v[i] = complex_downcast(v);
    }
};

buffer<double, 1> buf;

buf.set(0, 2.1); // Sets 2.1, cast to int8 and stored
std::cout << buf[0] << std::endl; // (double) 2.0000000
// Want: replace buf.set(index, value) by buf[index] = value, where complex_downcast is required.
```

Comment: Please post your code.  Descriptions of code don't communicate well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is have the array class overload the `operator[]` to return a *proxy* object, and then have the proxy overload `operator=` for writing and `operator T` for reading.  Then your proxy's operators can do whatever you want.

Try something like this:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N> struct buffer {
    int8_t v[N];

    struct proxy {
        int8_t *elem;
        proxy& operator=(T value) {
            // whatever you need...
            *elem = static_cast<T>(value);
            return *this;
        }
        operator T() const {
            // whatever you need... 
            return static_cast<T>(*elem);
        }
    };

    proxy operator[](int i) {
        return proxy{ &v[i]; };
    }
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/HwV1Rj)

Comment: Might be worth noting that having a proxy reference is a departure from _Standard Container_ semantics, which prevents some standard algorithms from working with it.  This is why `std::vector<bool>` is sometimes problematic to work with.

Comment: Note that this code is a great start, but you'll need additional complexity for `const` correctness. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33ce1a39678fcf43